# Is it possible to Deploy LWC straight to Production - If not, why?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Why can't we deploy an LWC straight to Production if there is no Data Manipulation and it is purely for visuals?

How can I actually test my LWC for >75% code coverage? I do not understand how and why this exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JEST provides you the ability to test your LWC or Javascript components. But it is not mandatory to cover your LWC components for deploying to production. 
You can changeset the component without any code coverage. However, if you did use any apex methods in the component and want to include the apex class in the changeset, then you will need to have code coverage for that class.